# How to remove tqdm progress bar in jupyter notebook once the loop breaks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I have tried the following methods

- Set *leave=False* or *disable=True*
- tqdm_iterator.close()

but they cannot remove the broken progress bar.

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
tqdm_iterator = tqdm(range(10000), leave=False)
for i in tqdm_iterator:
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    if i>8000:
        tqdm_iterator.n = 10000
        break
```

[broken progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLAxO.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `leave=False` parameter only removes the display bar after it *finishes*, ex. when the counter reaches `10000`. If you want to clear the progress bar output immediately, you can do `tqdm_iterator.container.close()`, like this:

```py
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
tqdm_iterator = tqdm(range(10000), leave=False)
for i in tqdm_iterator:
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    if i > 8000:
        tqdm_iterator.container.close()
        break
```